# Amazon AWS EC2, How to combines instances?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am able to create separate instances on amazon EC2.

I'm trying to use auto-scale to create more instances if the CPU utilization is over a percentage, but before that, I want to know how to combines instances in the EC2 console.

I think there's two ways that you can do it in a command line tool.
1. Auto Scale
2. CloudWatch

Is it possible to not use the command line tools, but control scaling on the website?

Also another questions is it possible to integrate the tools in java? I know you can create CloudWatch instances in java and trying to get the CPU utilization. Is there way to scale using the Amazon AWS Java SDK?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine 2 more ec2 instances you need to attach the instances to the ELastic Load Balancer. You can set your auto scaling configuration using also its better to monitor your instance using another micro instance and set the as configuration in that instance. Regarding JAVA SDK is you can, but in that sense your are just re inventing the wheel. Use the existing tools  instead of develop your own tool.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to use the Java SDK because many things can be done programmatically, so I just wanted to see if I can combine ec2 instances using Java.